# What is the JSON:API standard of sending extra information about the resource?

Tags: response, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I have an **endpoint** that responds with data to be filled in a **sortable** table. But some columns are not sortable columns and I want to communicate those columns in my response using **JSON:API** specifications.

I didn't find much information about these specifics.

So what is the best way to communicate this kind of data with the API consumer?

> One opinion that I am inclined to, is to put them in the metadata
>   field!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON:API allows you to provide *non-standard meta-information* using a [meta object](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#document-meta). The meta information could be for the full document, per resource or per relationship of a resource. The information which fields are supported for sorting is a meta information for the full document.

The specification does not cover how to format such meta informations. I'm also not aware of any recommendation or profile which covers your use case. So you should come up with your API specific implementation. E.g. you could provide an array of fields that could be used for sorting under `sortable` key of meta object. You may use dot-separated paths if you supporting sorting by fields of a  relationship. This would be inline with the value of `included` query param.

An example may look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    { 
      "type": "posts",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "An example post",
        "createdAt": "2019-08-05T11:11:11.000Z",
        "body": "..."
      },
      "relationships": {
        "author": {
          // ...
        },
      }
    },
    // ...
  },
  "meta": {
    "sortable": [
      "author.name",
      "createdAt",
      "title"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please note that I'm talking of *fields*. JSON:API specification does not have the term *columns* used in your question but I'm quite sure that you mean *fields* as [defined by spec](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-fields):

> A resource object’s attributes and its relationships are collectively called its “fields”.